# Device does not reboot when I press power button for more than 10 seconds

Tags: android

I am coding on a device having android source code. On normal android devices, when I long press the power button for 10 seconds, the device reboots however in my case, when I long press the power button for 10 seconds, the device turns off. Do you have an idea, where in the android source code, this functionality is coded (so that I ll understand where is my problem)?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7d276c3/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java

```
private final Runnable mPowerLongPress = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // The context isn't read
        if (mLongPressOnPowerBehavior < 0) {
            mLongPressOnPowerBehavior = mContext.getResources().getInteger(
                    com.android.internal.R.integer.config_longPressOnPowerBehavior);
        }
        switch (mLongPressOnPowerBehavior) {
        case LONG_PRESS_POWER_NOTHING:
            break;
        case LONG_PRESS_POWER_GLOBAL_ACTIONS:
            mPowerKeyHandled = true;
            performHapticFeedbackLw(null, HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS, false);
            sendCloseSystemWindows(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS);
            showGlobalActionsDialog();
            break;
        case LONG_PRESS_POWER_SHUT_OFF:
            mPowerKeyHandled = true;
            performHapticFeedbackLw(null, HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS, false);
            sendCloseSystemWindows(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS);
            ShutdownThread.shutdown(mContext, true);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Ha great! but quick question: on the case LONG_PRESS_POWER_SHUT_OFF, I can see at the end: ShutdownThread.shutdown(mContext, true);
DOes that mean that the device will turnoff when long press power button? In this case, why android devices reboot and does not simply turn off

Comment: Oh sorry, the code I highlighted isn't for the 10-second long press but a normal "long-press" (usually bringing up a context menu). I'm not sure where the 10-second one is, but I'd imagine it's in that same file.

Comment: Well...I had already seen this file...I put break points everywhere...but i really didnt find :(

Comment: Basically after a long press  can see that  am going to LONG_PRESS_POWER_GLOBAL_ACTIONS: and the power dialog appears....but that s all...

Comment: I'd bet it's actually built into the kernel, since this function needs to work even when the phone is off (or even bricked). Possibly somewhere in here: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.9-p-release/kernel/power/